# read int** from file C

Tags: c

I have to read a file in C and create an `int**`.

This is the file:

```
2
-1,1,1,0,0,1
1,-1,0,1,0
```

I'm doing this:

```
FILE *fp = fopen("grafo.txt", "r");
char line[100];
int numLinea = 0;
char** tokens;

while (1) {
    if (fgets(line,150, fp) == NULL) break;
    if(numLinea == 0){
        NUMERO_NODOS = atoi( line );
        nodos = (int **)malloc (NUMERO_NODOS*sizeof(int *));
    }else{
        tokens = str_split(line, ',');
        if (tokens) {
            for (int i = 0; *(tokens + i); i++) {
                char* contactoNodo;
                strcpy(contactoNodo, *(tokens + i));
                int numNodo = numLinea-1;
                nodos[numNodo] = (int *) malloc (NUMERO_NODOS*sizeof(int));
                nodos[numNodo][i] = atoi(contactoNodo);
                printf("nodos[%i][%i] = %i\n",numNodo,i,nodos[numNodo][i]);
                printf("nodos[0][0] = %i\n",nodos[0][0]);
                //free(contactoNodo);
            }
            printf("nodos[0][0] = %i\n",nodos[0][0]);
            //free(tokens);
        }
    }
    numLinea++;
    //printf("%3d: %s", i, line);
}
```

And this is the output:

```
nodos[0][0] = -1
nodos[0][0] = -1
nodos[0][1] = 1
nodos[0][0] = -1163005939
(...)
```

Why is `nodos[0][0] = -1163005939` in the second iteration of the for loop?

---

**SOLUTION**

LOL, it was that:

```
if(i==0){
      nodos[numNodo] = (int *) malloc (NUMERO_NODOS*sizeof(int));
}
```

I can't believe I didn't see it. Thanks MikeCAT!!!

Comment: Please post complete code, we don't need to guess what e.g. `NUMERO_NODOS` is supposed to be.

Comment: You invoked *undefined behavior* by using value of uninitialized variable `contactoNodo` having automatic storage duration, which is indeteminate.

Comment: Using value in buffer allocated via `malloc` and not initialized will also invoke *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Sorry, NUMERO_NODOS is the first line of file that indicate the number of lines

Comment: Why don't you use `tokens[i]` instead of `*(tokens + i)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fatal errors:

- You invoked *undefined behavior* by using value of uninitialized variable `contactoNodo` having automatic storage duration, which is indeteminate.
- You threw away what is read in the first iteration by allocating new buffer and overwriting the pointer to old buffer by it, and invoked *undefined behavior* again by reading contents of buffer allocated via `malloc` and not initialized.

Warnings:

- You should pass correct (equals or less than the actual buffer size) buffer size to `fgets()` to avoid buffer overrun.
- They say [you shouldn't cast the result of `malloc()` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Try this:

```
FILE *fp = fopen("grafo.txt", "r");
char line[100];
int numLinea = 0;
char** tokens;

while (1) {
    /* use correct buffer size to avoid buffer overrun */
    if (fgets(line,sizeof(line), fp) == NULL) break;
    if(numLinea == 0){
        NUMERO_NODOS = atoi( line );
        /* remove cast of what is returned from malloc() */
        nodos = malloc (NUMERO_NODOS*sizeof(int *));
    }else{
        tokens = str_split(line, ',');
        if (tokens) {
            for (int i = 0; *(tokens + i); i++) {
                char contactoNodo[100]; /* allocate buffer statically */
                strcpy(contactoNodo, *(tokens + i));
                int numNodo = numLinea-1;
                if (i == 0) { /* allocate buffer in only the first iteration */
                    /* remove cast of what is returned from malloc() */
                    nodos[numNodo] = malloc (NUMERO_NODOS*sizeof(int));
                }
                nodos[numNodo][i] = atoi(contactoNodo);
                printf("nodos[%i][%i] = %i\n",numNodo,i,nodos[numNodo][i]);
                printf("nodos[0][0] = %i\n",nodos[0][0]);
                /* do not free() what is not allocated via memory management functions such as malloc() */
            }
            printf("nodos[0][0] = %i\n",nodos[0][0]);
            //free(tokens);
        }
    }
    numLinea++;
    //printf("%3d: %s", i, line);
}
```